# Which JRE should I install for macros in Libre Office for Xenial

Tags: libreoffice, 16.04, jre

I have a clean Ubuntu 16.04 install, and opening Libre Office, it said it requires a JRE installed before I can run or write macros. I want to write VBA macros.

Running `apt search jre` shows many versions. Which should be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only reason you want a JRE is for LibreOffice, just install `openjdk-9-jre`.

The other 'main' JRE is Oracle's JRE, which contains proprietary code and is not in the repos. You'd need to manually download and install it. It's probably easier to not bother with it.